# getDatabase without server paramter does not work on R8

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

I've got a script like this `getDatabase("", "PATH/DATABASE.nsf")` and it works on a Notes R7 client. But in the Notes R8 client it trys to get the database from local. Is there a database property or somthing like this to tell the script it shut look an the same server where the database script runs. I know i can set the servername in the first parameter. But there are a lot of these script in my database and i don't whant to correct all of them.

Thanks

Comment: To be honest I'm surprised that worked in R7!  If you end up having to go down the route of changing all your code you could either do a mass find and replace using a TeamStudio product, or maybe even by using the 8.5 design client. Then could replace "getDatabase(""," with "getDatabase("Myserver"," in one go (or a constant)

Comment: Yes, i know, but masschanging is always a risk. But thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking at your problem wrong.

Your code is working fine and the functionality hasn't changed since Notes 5 (backward compatibility is not something you need to worry about with Lotus Notes).

This code looks for the database on the "current" server. So it should be working if it runs on server, but **fails if you run it manually**. Because when you run this code in your client the "current server" is Local.

Schedule the agent (I assume) and wait for it to run and confirm this.

If you are having difficulties getting the database I would encourage you to check the path, case and "/" vs "\" to see if they are all correct.

edit: If your code works on LN 7 when run locally, then you had you database in your **local** LN7 /data/PATH/DATABASE.nsf

Comment: i think thats a good hint. i think they got a local replica from the database. thanks